# Ignoring Non-Lower Case Characters in C

Tags: c

I am required to write a code which reads in a string, and places letters in the string that are less than 'm' into an array called first and the letters that are 'm' or greater are placed into an array called last. When it encounters a non-lower case letter it should simply skip it and move to the next one.

My code here works only when non-lower case letters are in the string but doesn't work when it involves numbers and symbols.

```
#include<stdio.h>

// main function
int main(void){
  // declare strings
  char letters[20], first[20], last[20];

  // read in a lower-case string
  printf("enter letters: ");
  scanf("%19s",letters);  //the number %19s limits the string to being
                          //19 characters long (plus the null character)

  // setup indexes to track current index of  arrays. 
  int letters_index, first_index, last_index;
  letters_index=0;
  first_index=0;
  last_index=0;
char curr_letter ;

  // loop and split
while(letters[letters_index] != 0) { // not null
    switch (letters[letters_index]){
        case 97 ... 122:
    curr_letter = letters[letters_index];
    // less than 'm'?
    if(curr_letter < 'm'){
      // add to first
      first[first_index]=curr_letter;
      first_index++;
    } else {
      // otherwise, add to last
      last[last_index]=curr_letter;
      last_index++;
    }
    letters_index++;
            break;
    }
}


  // now add nulls
  first[first_index]='\0';
  last[last_index]='\0';

  // print arrays
  printf("first: %s\n",first);
  printf("last: %s\n",last);
}
```

If the input is hell2o, the output should be first: hell; last :o

Comment: Note that code such as `case 97 ... 122` is a non-standard extension to the C language and is not portable.

Comment: Can you use `<ctype.h>` and macros such as `islower()`?  If so, do so.  You seem to be using an extension (over standard C) with the `case 97 ... 122:` notation — I guess it is a GCC extension. That’s OK as long as you’re cognizant that it is not standard C.  But you should use `case ‘a’ ... ‘l’:` and `case ‘m’ ... ‘z’:` to split the letters.

Comment: And in any case it would probably be better to explicitly use `'a' ... 'z'`

Comment: Also, please fix the indentation. The code is very difficult to read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code increments `letters_index` only if the input matches `case 97 ... 122:`. It is an endless loop if a non-matching character is found.

Move the incrementing `letters_index++;` out of the `switch{}` to the end of the `while` loop.

Unrelated to the error: Instead of the numbers `97` and `122` you should use the corresponding character constants `'a'` and `'z'` or maybe the library function `islower()`.

Modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// main function
int main(void){
    // declare strings
    char letters[20], first[20], last[20];

    // read in a lower-case string
    printf("enter letters: ");
    scanf("%19s",letters);  //the number %19s limits the string to being
    //19 characters long (plus the null character)

    // setup indexes to track current index of  arrays. 
    int letters_index, first_index, last_index;
    letters_index=0;
    first_index=0;
    last_index=0;
    char curr_letter ;

    // loop and split
    while(letters[letters_index] != 0) { // not null
        switch (letters[letters_index]){
        case 'a' ... 'z':
        curr_letter = letters[letters_index];
        // less than 'm'?
        if(curr_letter < 'm'){
            // add to first
            first[first_index]=curr_letter;
            first_index++;
        } else {
            // otherwise, add to last
            last[last_index]=curr_letter;
            last_index++;
        }
        break;
        }
        letters_index++;
    }


    // now add nulls
    first[first_index]='\0';
    last[last_index]='\0';

    // print arrays
    printf("first: %s\n",first);
    printf("last: %s\n",last);
}
```

Comment: @user672518 If it helped you could accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You only increase the counter when the character is between `'a'`  and `'z'`, in consequence you are running into an infinite loop, move the counter outside the `switch`:

```
while(letters[letters_index] != 0) { // not null
    switch (letters[letters_index]){
        case 97 ... 122:
            curr_letter = letters[letters_index];
            // less than 'm'?
            if(curr_letter < 'm'){
              // add to first
              first[first_index]=curr_letter;
              first_index++;
            } else {
              // otherwise, add to last
              last[last_index]=curr_letter;
              last_index++;
            }
            // letters_index++; --> Not here
            break;
    }
    letters_index++; // --> Here
}
```

On the other hand, do not use magic numbers like 97 and 122, instead:

```
case 'a' ... 'z':
```